# I have a error while inserting this data into a table which has a unique FK because it is a 1 to 1 relationship

Tags: postgresql

**PostgreSQL question:**

ERD for my schema:

[image]

When I run this insert command:

```
INSERT INTO fighter (address_id, house_number, street, city, st, zip, fighter_id)
   VALUES (1, 1358, 'Orchid Circle', 'Bellport', 'NY', '11713', 1);
```

the compiler tells me

```
column "address_id" of relation "fighter" does not exist
```

I have no idea why I am getting the bug. Can someone help me fix this minor error?

Comment: According to your schema, `fighter` does not have a column `address_id`. Why does the error message surprise you?

Comment: foreign key constraints require a primary key record